# ruby reject only certain duplicates from an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to reject duplicates from an array of hashes based on the count of duplicates( >=3).

For eg: The criteria for a duplicate is just the name, regardless of the number.

```
a = [{:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567"},
         {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567"},
              {:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>"5557654321"},
               {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567"}]
```

I want to reject the "names" which are duplicated more than 2 times.
The function should return:

```
[{:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>"5557654321"}]
```

I tried below which is probably incorrect:

```
a.group_by{|e| e}.select{ |k, v| k[:name].size >=3}.reject
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is O(n) and might do better on a larger list:

```
a.group_by { |el| el[:name] }.reject { |_, v| v.size > 2 }.values.flatten
```

Comment: This does not preserve the order of the elements of the given array.

Answer (score 3):

[`Enumerable#reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) and [`Enumerable#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) might help:

```
arr = [
    {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567"},
    {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567"},
    {:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>"5557654321"},
    {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567"}
]
p arr.reject { |hsh| arr.count(hsh) > 2 }
# => [{:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>"5557654321"}]
```

Based on the comment, adding the use [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
names = arr.map { |hsh| hsh[:name] }
p arr.reject { |hsh| names.count(hsh[:name]) > 2 }
```

Comment: i want only duplicate name count. the above code considers name and number

Comment: Not a problem at all. Almost the same with just an additional operation.

Comment: Using `count` here is relatively inefficient as it must be repeated for each element  of the array, making its computational complexity O(n^2). I'm sure you know there are ways of making those counts that are O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we are give the following array (which differs from that given in the question).

```
arr = [{ :name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567" },
       { :name=>"John Doe3", :number=>"5551234567" },
       { :name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567" },
       { :name=>"John Doe2", :number=>"5557654321" },
       { :name=>"John Doe3", :number=>"5551234567" },
       { :name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567" }]
```

We can obtain the desired value as follows.

```
arr.values_at(*arr.each_with_index.with_object({}) { |(g,i),h| (h[g] ||= []) << i }.
    values.
    select { |a| a.size < 3 }.
    flatten.
    sort)
  #=> [{:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>"5551234567"},
  #    {:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>"5557654321"},
  #    {:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>"5551234567"}]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
enum0 = arr.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: [{:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567"},
  #                  {:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>"5551234567"},
  #                   ...
  #                  {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567"}]:each_with_index>
enum1 = enum0.with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator:
  #     #<Enumerator: [{:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567"},
  #                    {:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>"5551234567"},
  #                    ...
  #                    {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567"}]:each_with_index>
  #   :with_object({})>
b = enum1.each { |(g,i),h| (h[g] ||= []) << i }
  #=> {{:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567"}=>[0, 2, 5],
  #    {:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>"5551234567"}=>[1, 4],
  #    {:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>"5557654321"}=>[3]}
c = b.values
  #=> [[0, 2, 5], [1, 4], [3]]
d = c.select { |a| a.size < 3 }
  #=> [[1, 4], [3]]
f = e.sort
  #=> [1, 3, 4]
arr.values_at(*f)
  #=> [{:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>"5551234567"},
  #    {:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>"5557654321"},
  #    {:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>"5551234567"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole answer has been re-written as inspired by @CarySwoveland (for previous implementations please feel free to look at the edits).

These 2 options seem to be the most efficient way possible to handle this situation

```
a.group_by { |el| el[:name] }.each_with_object([]) do |(_, v),obj| 
  obj.concat(v) if v.size < 3 
end
#or 
a.group_by { |el| el[:name] }.flat_map { |_, v| v if v.size < 3 }.compact
```

Comment: Using `count` is relatively inefficient. See my commnet on @Sebastain's answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank you for the inspiration. I have updated my answer completely and both options are more efficient than all the other answers posted according to fruity.